# -24 Google Play Error on installing eBay

Tags: applications, google-play-store, apk

Whenever I try to install the eBay app from the play store I get a -24 error code: "unknown error when installing application". I have googled the error and I cannot find anything relating to this. Anyone know what this error is and how to fix it? 
I can install other apps. I have an S4 on Kit Kat (4.4.2). I have forced stopped the play store and cleared the data on play services and play store.

Comment: Are you using ART runtime?

Comment: No. I can't change the runtime on S4 stock. I'm still using dalvik.

Comment: Go to data/data and try deleting the folder named with com.something.ebay.. (you need to be root)

Comment: I dont have root :(. Is there another way (like using ADB?)

Comment: I dont know how to do via adb but a factory reset will fix the issue

Comment: @GAThrawn. This is different. I do not even have the app installed. I have cleared data and cache on play store and servives.

Comment: *Whenever I try to install...* implies you've already tried before. Did you get the "-24" error on the very first try as well? For all subsequent tries, the dupe-marked question would apply, as the first install failed (even if for a different reason, but this is about your current situation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a root explorer, then go to `data/data` (of your phone not the sd card) and delete the folders of apps you want to  install and reinstall those apps from playstore.

If you dont have root, a factory reset will do.